# Comparar entre horarios en php

Tags: php, sql, pdo, condiciones

Hola mi nombre es Sergio y necesito ayuda con un proyecto en el que trabajo y no tengo mucha experiencia con PHP.
Estoy implementando un sistema de agenda de turnos y para registrar un turno antes debo verificar que no esté ocupado entre hora inicial y hora final deseada.
Pero no me toma la consulta sql y no encuentro cual es el problema.
Sera que alguien me puede orientar?

Hora inicial y hora final lo paso a date para poder operar con esos datos porque eran string.

Ingreso los valores de las variables para que sea mas facil la ayuda.
En la base de datos existe ya un registro con esos datos en HORA_INICIO = 16:30:00, HORA_FINAL= 17:00:00), $FECHA= 2022-01-06.

```
$fecha= 2022-01-06
$hora_i= 16:00:00
$hora_f= 17:00:00

$Hora_Final = strtotime($hora_fin);
$hora_f = date('H:i:s',$Hora_Final);

$Hora_Inicial = strtotime($hora_ini);
$hora_i = date('H:i:s',$Hora_Inicial);

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM turnos WHERE HORA_INICIO >= " . $hora_i . " AND HORA_FINAL <= " . $hora_f . " AND FECHA = " . $fecha ;
 $fe = mysql_query($consulta);
 if ($fe == true){
  echo ' <script>  alert("Mensaje error, El turno entre esos horarios ya esta ocupado.")</script>';
  
}
else {
  $consulta = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO turnos(FECHA,NOMBRE_PACIENTE,NOMBRE_SUCURSAL,PROFESIONAL,HORA_INICIO,HORA_FINAL,TRATAMIENTO,EQUIPO,CATEGORIA_ZONA,ZONA,COMENTARIOS) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");    
  $result = $consulta->execute([$fecha,$paciente,$sucursal,$usuario,$hora_i,$hora_f,$trata,$equipo,$cate_zona,$zona,$coment]);
 
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es $fecha?   No lo veo.  tampoco veo que encierres las variables entre comillas simples, asi:  `'" . hora_i . "'` ni nos dices que error te da.  Léete [ask], haz el [tour] e intenta hacer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte mucho mejor, gracias

Comment: Los valores alfanuméricos (incluidas las fechas/horas) deben ir entre comillas. Prueba de este modo: **`$consulta = "SELECT * FROM turnos WHERE HORA_INICIO >= '$hora_i' AND HORA_FINAL <=  '$hora_f' AND FECHA = '$fecha'" ;`** Para evitar confusiones, he metido todo dentro de la cadena con dobles comillas, así, puedes usar al interior comillas simples y variables, teniendo un código más limpio. Por otro lado, te recomiendo vivamente que uses una columna `DATETIME` en la que guardes fecha y hora. Si se da el caso que un turno empiece un día/hora y termine al día siguiente todo se complicará.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de datos tienen las columnas HORA_INICIO, HORA_FINAL y FECHA en la base de datos?

Comment: La HORA_INICIO en la base de datos es valor TIME tambien HORA_FINAL y la FECHA es DATE

Comment: Tendrias que aprender a depurar lo que haces y activar la visualización de los errores. No le veo sentido a que por un lado uses `mysql_query` (función obsoleta desde PHP 5.4 y eliminada desde la versión 7.x) , y por el otro, uses PDO al final de tu pregunta. Para activarla pon esto al principio de tu php:  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`.  Con eso conseguiras ver que te falla y darnos mejor información de tu problema.

Comment: Cortar y pegar código sin ton ni son y esperar que nosotros lo resolvamos es una mala idea. Ni tu aprendes bien ni nosotros nos motivamos a ayudarte más. Cuando hayas activado los errores y te salgan por pantalla investigalos y arreglalos si puedes, y si despues de agotar todos tus recursos no te sale bien entonces vienes y nos lo cuentas de nuevo, y veremos que podemos hacer.

Comment: Tienes errores desde la primera linea, pues no entrecomillas las igualdades de las variables, y el parser de PHP seguro que te mostrará errores cuando los puedas visualizar.  Mientras tanto seguramente solo obtienes páginas en blanco.

Answer (score 2):

Puede ser porque estás usando el signo + en vez del punto "." para concatenar...

Pon esto:

```
$consulta = "SELECT HORA_INICIO,HORA_FINAL,FECHA FROM turnos WHERE HORA_INICIO >= " . $hora_ini . " AND HORA_FINAL <= " . $hora_fin . " AND FECHA = " . $fecha ;
```

en lugar de esto:

```
$consulta = "SELECT HORA_INICIO,HORA_FINAL,FECHA FROM turnos WHERE HORA_INICIO >= " + $hora_ini + " AND HORA_FINAL <= " + $hora_fin + " AND FECHA = " + $fecha ;
```

Comment: Hola, ya probe con .  y me pasa igual , pasa por alto la consulta

Comment: Te estás columpiando, @masterguru, porque yo le he indicado que use el `.` en vez del `+`, y él ha editado su pregunta para adaptarlo. Comprueba las ediciones...

Comment: Solo es una expresión coloquial, por el -1... ;D

Comment: No pasa nada, solo es un número...

Comment: Vale, gracias...

Answer (score 0):

En SQL, los valores alfanuméricos (incluidas las fechas/horas) deben ir entre comillas.

Prueba de este modo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM turnos WHERE HORA_INICIO >= '$hora_i' AND HORA_FINAL <=  '$hora_f' AND FECHA = '$fecha'";
```

Si observas, para evitar confusiones, he metido todo dentro de la cadena con dobles comillas, así, puedes usar al interior comillas simples y variables, teniendo un código más limpio.

Salvo otros errores, así debería funcionar.

### Recomendaciones

- Te recomiendo vivamente que uses dos columnas `DATETIME` en la que guardes fecha y hora de entrada y salida. Algo así:

  ```
   FECHA_INICIO                FECHA_FIN
   -------------------------------------------------
   2022-01-07 06:00:00         2022-01-07 13:00:00
   2022-01-07 23:59:00         2022-01-08 06:00:00
  ```

  Observa la segunda fila, entró un minuto antes de que acabara el día, y ¡salió al día siguiente!. Si en un futuro se da este caso en tu sistema ¡tendrás que manejarlo con **cuatro columnas**! 2 para la fecha de inicio / fin  + 2 para la hora de inicio/fin. Declarando dos columnas DATETIME tienes flexibilidad en todo y encima usas una columna menos que el diseño actual (estás usando tres columnas). Además, los cálculos, ordenaciones, comparaciones, etc son más fáciles.
- Considera usar *Consultas preparadas* para dar seguridad a tu código, el cual actualmente es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas lee sobre el tema y considera escribir un código seguro.